# How to store data in laravel 8 using Ajax Call with multiple images

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to store data in a database in Laravel, but the issue is I am able to save the directly using controller.

Now I am using image order change that it working with the jQuery.

After changing orders of the images, I get the json data in which images sources are stored.

Now I want to store the data with image file location(that I will get when I use laravel file storage to convert base64 image src and save it in the disk).

So, only the image src are coming from the josn, the rest I am using `Laravel request->input()` for.

Here is the Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Initialize sortable
    $("#sortable").sortable();

    // Save order
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var imageids_arr = [];
        // get image ids order
        $('#sortable li').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var json = {
                           id : id,
                           src : $(this).data('src')
                       }
            imageids_arr.push(json);
        });

        console.log(imageids_arr);
        var ajaxurl = '/api/add_ref_images_first';

        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {imageids: imageids_arr},
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response == 1)
                            alert('Save successfully.');
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

Controller code:

```
 public function add_product(Request $request) {
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'short_description' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'parent_id' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'sku' => 'required',
        'publisher' => 'required',
        'thumbnail' => 'required',
        'product_images' => 'required',
    );
    $messages = [

    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {
        $product_id = 'PUBP' . time();
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $author = $request->input('author');
        $short_description = $request->input('short_description');
        $long_description = $request->input('description');
        $parent_id = $request->parent_id;
        $tags = $request->input('tags');
        $price = $request->input('price');
        $sku = $request->input('sku');
        $quantity = $request->input('quantity');
        $tax = $request->input('tax');
        $selling_price = $request->input('offer_price');
        $added_by = Cookie::get('admin_id');
        $publisher = $request->input('publisher');
        $thumbnail = "";
        $thumbnail = $this->thumbnail($request->file('thumbnail'), $product_id);
        $product_images = "";
        $product_images = $this->product_images($request->file('product_images'), $product_id);
//            Note :  Here I want the save the image file and get the location
//            return $parent_id;
        // Saving Data
        $result = Product::create([
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'name'=>$name,
            'author'=>$author,
            'slug' => \Str::slug($name),
            'short_description'=>$short_description,
            'description' => $long_description,
            'parent_id' => $parent_id,
            'tags' => $tags,
            'price' => $price,
            'sku' => $sku,
            'publisher' => $publisher,
            'thumbnail' => $thumbnail,
            'images' => $product_images,
            'added_by' => $added_by,
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'tax' => $tax,
            'offer_price' => $selling_price,
            'meta_title' => $name,
            'meta_description'=> $short_description,
            'meta_keywords'=> $tags,
            'status' => '0',
        ])->categories()->sync(explode(',',$parent_id));

        if($result){
            return redirect('/admin/products')->with( [ 'status' => "Product Uploaded Successfully" ] );
        }else{
            return redirect('/admin/products')->with( [ 'status' => "Something went wrong" ] );
        }

    }

}
```

Ref image store code:

```
public function product_images($ref_images, $folder_name) {
    $fileName = "";
    $end_url = "";
    $count = 0;

    foreach($ref_images as $image)
    {
        $ref_image_id = 'PUBR'.time().$count++.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $image->storeAs($folder_name, $ref_image_id , ['disk' => 'my_uploaded_files']);
        if($fileName){
            $end_url = $end_url.$fileName.',';
        }
    }
    return $end_url;
}
```

Json data screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
use Image; 
if ($request->file('product_images')) {
                        $image = $request->file('product_images');
                        $ext = explode('/',substr($request->product_images, 0, strpos($request->product_images,';')))[1];
                        $img->save($end_url);
                    }
```

Comment: I am stuck in how to send data from blade file using Ajax and mix that data with controller

Comment: you are already send you image based64 format on your controller

Comment: $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {imageids: imageids_arr},
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response == 1)
                            alert('Save successfully.');
                    }
                }); // Send Your data using post method use Image;

Comment: then your based64 encoded image is you can get using controller  then you can use this code like this. if ($request->imageids) {
                        $image = $request->file('imageids');
                        $ext = explode('/',substr($request->imageids, 0, strpos($request->imageids,';')))[1];
                        $img->save($end_url);
                    }

Comment: I tried, But whenever I click on the submit button, It says, 500 error, I already set token in ajaxSetup

Comment: can you share screen shot your console and network